# I have a div and a image and I need them aligned in the middle of the screen

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #292929;
}
.holder {
  width: 66%;
  height: 330px;
  background-color: #412A22;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px #000000;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0px #000000;
  display: inline-block;
}
.holder:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid #292929;
    border-right: 50px solid #412A22;
    width: 0;
}
.sidething {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main">
 <div class="holder">
  <div class="holder-imgs">
  </div>
  <div class="contact">   
  </div>
 </div>
 <img class="sidething" src="Layer%203.png">
 </div>
```

This is my css and html and what i basicly need is to center both image and div in the middle of the page. Here is what it looks like with image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjJee.jpg

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something simple like this:

```
<center>
<div class="main">
<div class="holder">
    <div class="holder-imgs">
    </div>
    <div class="contact">           
    </div>
</div>
<img class="sidething" src="Layer%203.png">
</div>
</center>
```

Simple HTML - should do the trick!

Or, if you're main 'holder' div will only contain text, you could add the following property to the 'holder' div css:

```
text-align: center;
```

You might find [this site](http://www.thesitewizard.com/css/center-div-block.shtml) useful!

Hope this helps and best of luck!